# VSCode: yarn, but got error: incorrect data check

Tags: visual-studio-code, yarnpkg

I cloned vscode repo and running `yarn` to install deps. But got an error:

```sh
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/xterm-addon-unicode11/-/xterm-addon-unicode11-0.3.0.tgz: incorrect data check".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/lsf/Code/github/js/vscode/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

---

update:

OS: MacOS Big Sur - 11.5.2 (Apple M1 chips)

node version: v14.18.1

yarn version: 1.22.10

Comment: have you tried clearing your cache with `yarn cache clean`

Comment: Yes, I have tried `yarn cache clean`. But it not works. Thanks for your instant reply.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is I installed `node v14.18.1` by `nvm`. Because of M1 mac, nvm build node from source code for me. But the output has problem with `yarn`.

What I do:
Remove the nvm-version node and install `Node-v14.18.1` on [Node official download address.](https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.18.1/node-v14.18.1.pkg)

Now, everything is perfect.

Comment: The installer installed as root, so I was not able to reinstall yarn globally (no permission). Do not want to sudo install global packages.

Comment: Just had this same issue with v16.18.1. This fixed it. ty.

Answer (score 3):

Switching arch from `arm64` to `x64` with nvm worked for me.

Steps,

1. Switch arch to `x64` by running `arch -x86_64 zsh`
2. Confirm arch is switched by running `arch`.
3. Run `nvm install 14` to install node v14.
4. Exit and start a new terminal to switch back to `arm64` arch.

Answer (score 2):

The is an compression issue with https://registry.yarnpkg.com/xterm-addon-unicode11/-/xterm-addon-unicode11-0.3.0.tgz. The file is not a proper Zlib compressed stream, and thus cannot be opened.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by appending `--shared-zlib` to the `nvm` command, like this:

```
nvm install v14.20.0 --shared-zlib
```

It's needed on M1 macs for Node.js versions prior to v16, according to the [nvm docs](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#macos-troubleshooting).

Comment: this resolved the issue for us with node 18